# Is the change of the integral order valid even when its integral diverges? - Integrability assumption in Tonelli theorem-

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I suddenly wondered if the change of the order of integral is valid even when its integral diverges.
For the presence, I knew that Tonelli's theorem is exactly it (from Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem) but I can not quite understand.

> **Is the integrability not necessary for Tonelli theorem?**
>   That is, if "$(X,A,\mu)$ and $(Y,B,\nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f:X\times Y\to[0,\infty]$ is measurable" are only assumed, then can we change the order of integrals?

Another notes I found are written that the integral is finite and the change of order of integrals (Fubini theorem) is basically needed the integrality, doesn't it.
I am confused because of these...

Could you tell me why Fubini like theorem holds even if the integrability is not assumed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is from wikipedia: "Fubini's theorem implies that the two repeated integrals of a function of two variables are equal if the function is integrable. Tonelli's theorem introduced by Leonida Tonelli (1909) is similar but applies to functions that are non-negative rather than integrable."

Comment: I couldn't understand also this sentence. That is, is Tonelli theorem imposed assumptions of Fubini theorem?

Comment: The statement you quoted in the yellow box is Tonelli's theorem and it is stated correctly. Indeed, you can apply Tonelli's theorem to nonnegative non integrable functions.